# Upgrade Http to HttpClient in Angular 5: "server responded with a status of 415 (Unsupported Media Type)"

Tags: angular, angular2-http, angular-httpclient

I've upgraded an app from Angular 4.2 to 5 but after changed `Http` to `HttpClient` got error on POST request:

> error the server responded with a status of 415 (Unsupported Media
>   Type)

in `app.module` I've imported `HttpClientModule`:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Old code:

```
 post(url: string, model: any): Observable<any> {
        let body = JSON.stringify(model);
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this._http.post(url, body, options)
            .map((response: Response) => <any>response.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

new code:

```
put(url: string, id: number, model: any): Observable<any> {
        let body = JSON.stringify(model);
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options: any = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this._http.put(url + id, body, options)
            .catch(this.handleError);        //only removed .map
    }
```

thanks

Comment: You need to rework the options and headers objects, please check https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request

Comment: hi.indeed,seems working  return this._http.post(url, body, { headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json') }
        )

Comment: read the docs, carefully and complete

Answer (score 6):

For me it worked without setting the Content-Type header when using an object as body instead of stringify-ing it. I guess that using a string as body makes Angular assume 'text/plain' as content type instead of the default 'application/json'.

So instead of your new code just use:

`return this._http.put(url + id, model).subscribe(..`

Comment: thank you so much for the hint. You are a real savior. :)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

It worked for me by checking the data type that is received from input type before being sent to service. In my case, I got "Id" from the dropdown list with string.
So, I used `parseInt` to change data type to number and then it worked.