# Can't change Content-Type in http post request using angular

Tags: angular, httpclient

I can't change Content-Type to application/json  in headers of post request. I use angular 6. 
Request is rejected with error (Unsupported Media Type)
Same request working with old http from '@angular/http'.

I use visual studio debug for running application. Web api is .net core.

```
import { HttpClient, HttpRequest, HttpEventType, HttpResponse, HttpHeaders 
} from '@angular/common/http';

var body = JSON.stringify(model);
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

let httpOptions = {headers: headers,};

this.http.post(this.Url, body, httpOptions).subscribe(x => { })
```

[Request result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnNrk.png)

Comment: You may want to check this- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47292568/upgrade-http-to-httpclient-in-angular-5-server-responded-with-a-status-of-415

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I used HttpInterceptor which replace request headers